# Validate if input number is in range from 1 to 60

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, range

I've an input text field as below.

```
<h:inputText id="number" maxlength="3" value="#{bean.entity.number}" />
```

I'd like to validate if the number is from 1 to 60 and show error otherwise. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can decorate the component with a `<f:validateLongRange>`. For example:

```
<h:inputText id="number" maxlength="3" value="#{bean.entity.number}">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="60" />
</h:inputText>
```

You'll get a validation error if the input doesn't meet the range set in the `validateLongRange`. You can customize the validation error with `validatorMessage` attribute.